# Installing Experience Optimization on Fredhopper - indexer is not starting

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper, web8, experience-optimization

**fredhopper version**: fredhopper-8.1-revision-1

Installed Experience Optimization on Fredhopper as per the [document](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-8BDDDAAD-BB27-4150-9121-C3283EA5A0C8&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-8BDDDAAD-BB27-4150-9121-C3283EA5A0C8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-8BDDDAAD-BB27-4150-9121-C3283EA5A0C8) steps and then provided full permission to fredhopper folder for admin user.

**Topology.txt**

```
ExperienceOptimization|localhost|1|-|Indexer and Preview environment for demo setup 
ExperienceOptimizationLive|localhost|2|ExperienceOptimization|Live Query Server for demo setup
```

Tried this command to started the indexer

```
bin\instance ExperienceOptimization start
```

Running for long time but it's not completed.

**Error in agent Log:**

> 2016-05-07 06:20:06,186 WARN  Cannot prepare logging for
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.processes.log.RollingLogPreparator@606f6eb4
>   (LogLaunchConfigurator.java:30) java.io.IOException: Could not create
>   directories for ExperienceOptimization    at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.Util.createDirectories(Util.java:366)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.Util.createParentDirectories(Util.java:357)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.processes.log.SimpleLogPreparator.prepareLog(SimpleLogPreparator.java:21)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.processes.log.RollingLogPreparator.prepareLog(RollingLogPreparator.java:38)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.processes.LogLaunchConfigurator.configure(LogLaunchConfigurator.java:27)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.Process.createLauncher(Process.java:280)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.fas.EntityMigratorProcess.runRuleBasedEntityMigration(EntityMigratorProcess.java:64)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.fas.TomcatQueryServerProcess.runMigrations(TomcatQueryServerProcess.java:240)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.fas.TomcatQueryServerProcess.start(TomcatQueryServerProcess.java:120)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.Process.executeVerb(Process.java:106)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.agent.resources.ProcessFacade.executeVerb(ProcessFacade.java:84)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:821)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:375)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Not sure this is the reason, but XO is not tested nor supported with FH 8.x, it's 7.5.x only.

Comment: Is that the only message in agent.log? This is a warning, likely pointing to permission issues with the Fredhopper directory.

Comment: @ankon: No. we have lot of INFO but this is the only one message appearing as WARN

Answer (score 4):

As @Ankon says, if you use different user during installation process (for example root for make some directories and Fredhopper for running) you probably have not rights on some directories.

Try to change the owner of $FREDHOPPER_HOME to fredhopper user with recursive options.

You should always use fredhopper user for running and maintenance.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: I agree. This looks like a classic file system permissions issue.

Comment: @Jose: No it's configured such a way, I know i used to installed domain admin user Domain\Velu and then I created a local system user "fredhopper" as admin user on the system I changed the fredhopper home folder to owner to fredhopper user my power script also running with same user.. for starting the fredhopper indexer.. I did reverified seems to be something else.. Because I went I verified all the logs and xml folders full permission is there for that user

Comment: After execute bin/ instance ExperienceOptimization start, you can check in your browser this page http://<Fredhopper>:8177/instance/ExperienceOptimization/process/qserver/verb/status  sometimes it takes a long time to start this service and finally you have a Time Out. If it is stopped, you can execute the next http://<Fredhopper>:8177/instance/ExperienceOptimization/process/qserver/verb/start

Answer (score 0):

As @Nuno mentioned above XO is not tested nor supported with FH 8.x, it's 7.5.x only.

[Support history: FAS](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-08A16472-FF81-4084-83A6-E96D11411320&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-5F3633DE-2233-4B39-A40C-7CC05A7A194D.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-08A16472-FF81-4084-83A6-E96D11411320) In Web8.

I did resolve this issue by Installing these versions

**fredhopper-7.5-revision-19.zip**

**fas-assembly-7.5.2.10.zip**