# Installing Experience Optimization 8 on Fredhopper - indexer is not starting on latest version fredhopper-8.1-revision-3

Tags: web8, fredhopper, sdl-tridion, experience-optimization

We are in the process of integrating the SDL Web 8.1 Experience Optimization with Topology setup with fredhopper latest version (**fredhopper-8.1-revision-3**) integration but we are getting the issue indexer is not starting it's takes longer time.

We have also noticed after downloading the fredhopper-8.1-revision-3 try to extract the zip file it's getting this Path Too Long.

[image]

But we managed to fixed this issue with WINRAR.

I have raised previously same issue like this with revion1 with Tridion stack exchange very long back, seems to be still it's not been fixed.

Topology - already running with Java8 JRE.. I can't install fredhopper-7.5.x because it needs Java7 jdk.

Refer to the old ticket
[Installing Experience Optimization on Fredhopper - indexer is not starting](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/installing-experience-optimization-on-fredhopper-indexer-is-not-starting)

Installed Experience Optimization on Fredhopper as per the document steps and then provided full permission to fredhopper folder for admin user.

**Topology.txt**

> indexer|localhost|1|-|Indexer and Preview environment for demo setup 
>   query|localhost|2|indexer|Live Query Server for demo setup Tried this

command to started the indexer

> bin\instance indexer start

Running for long time but it's not completed.

**agent.log**

> 2016-10-10 16:27:44,125 WARN  Cannot prepare logging for
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.processes.log.RollingLogPreparator@400d13a8
>   (LogLaunchConfigurator.java:30) java.io.IOException: Could not create
>   directories for indexer   at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.Util.createDirectories(Util.java:366)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.Util.createParentDirectories(Util.java:357)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.processes.log.SimpleLogPreparator.prepareLog(SimpleLogPreparator.java:21)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.processes.log.RollingLogPreparator.prepareLog(RollingLogPreparator.java:38)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.impl.processes.LogLaunchConfigurator.configure(LogLaunchConfigurator.java:27)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.Process.createLauncher(Process.java:280)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.fas.EntityMigratorProcess.runRuleBasedEntityMigration(EntityMigratorProcess.java:67)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.fas.TomcatQueryServerProcess.runMigrations(TomcatQueryServerProcess.java:240)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.fas.TomcatQueryServerProcess.start(TomcatQueryServerProcess.java:120)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.core.Process.executeVerb(Process.java:106)
>     at
>   com.fredhopper.deployment.agent.resources.ProcessFacade.executeVerb(ProcessFacade.java:84)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:821)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:375)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 2016-10-10 16:27:44,125 INFO 
>   Executing: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe
>   -Dapp-name=migrate-rule-based-entities -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:/fredhopper/bin/../data/installations/FAS/etc/log4j-cmdline.xml
>   -Dfas.jcr.readOnly=false -Dlog-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin..\data\instances\indexer\log -Dbase-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin..\data\instances\indexer -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Detc-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin..\data\installations\FAS\etc -Dconfig-dir=C:\fredhopper\bin..\data\instances\indexer\config -cp C:\fredhopper\bin..\data\installations\FAS\lib*;C:\fredhopper\bin..\data\instances\indexer\custom*;
>   com.fredhopper.application.EntityMigratorApp -c
>   (VerboseStartupLogConfigurator.java:55) 2016-10-10 17:27:45,124 ERROR
>   Migration in com.fredhopper.deployment.core.Instance@73d448ff has
>   timed out (EntityMigratorProcess.java:81)

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote from the [prerequisites section of the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-60A50714-1D73-4EBF-953A-3E20F63DB3CD):

> SDL Web Experience Optimization 8 requires **version 7.5.x** of Fredhopper Access Server.

You cannot use version 8 as there are breaking changes (it's a new major version, after all).

You can use Java 8 with the later versions of Fredhopper. I recommend you use version 7.5.2.10 or higher.

Comment: Thanks, same confirmed by Andy from SDL, could you please help me where can I find this version on fredhopper.

Comment: It's available on the extranet site, under Downloads. I can't give you a direct link right now as I don't have access to it at the moment. If you don't already have the platform, you should first download and install the latest 7.5 one (deployment/fredhopper-7.5-revision-19.zip I believe) and then upgrade the FAS inside of that to the latest version (7.5.2.11, I think). There's a rather lengthy section of the Learning Center devotes to this: https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Install%2C+deploy+and+operate

Comment: By the way, if you've never done any of this before, expect some "growing pains". If you can get an experienced implementer to help you, I recommend you ask for that as it is not trivial to get Fredhopper up and running (unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks for this, I have worked mainly on fredhopper-7.5-revision-15.zip with SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 It was working fine with load balanced integrated system with enterprise client.

I was started looking to integrating the SDL Web 8 XO with fredhopper-7.5-revision-19.zip some think I don't know really we can use different version for FAS and again I got done all these steps but now qserver is not starting for Business manager it's getting 500 error